# How to delay displaying of Game Center's popup window?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, game-center

I have integrated Game Center (GC) into my game. It works great, except for an annoying message, which can popup in the middle of intense action, requiring 100% of the gamer's attention:

> "Could not  connect to Game Center server. Cancel/Retry?"

I don't mind about the message, but the information is not so urgent it has to be displayed immediately. I would like to display it after the user has navigated to the main menu or at some other point. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: I hope you find an answer to this, it _really_ annoys me in games!

Answer (score 2):

Delaying the following login call for game center did the trick for me.

```
if([GameCenterManager isGameCenterAvailable]){
    gameCenterManager = [[GameCenterManager alloc] init];
    [gameCenterManager setDelegate:self];
    [gameCenterManager authenticateLocalUser];

    NSLog(@"Game center logged in");
}
else 
    NSLog(@"Please login to game center");
```

Comment: May all game developers see your answer.